# Convert sql to use transaction

Tags: vb.net

I would like to convert my current sql to use transaction feature. So far i did raw sql function as you can see below. How to convert it to use also transaction within that function?

```
Public Function GetAllByKatId(Id As Integer) As Object
    Dim result As Object
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Clear()
    Using cnn As New SqlConnection(strcon)
        cnn.Open()
        Using dad As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbGet WHERE ID=@id", cnn)
            dad.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@id", Id))
            dad.Fill(dt)

            If dt IsNot Nothing AndAlso dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                result = dt
            Else
                result = Nothing
            End If
        End Using
        cnn.Close()
    End Using
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Every query statement already runs within a transaction - there's no point in adding an extra one when we're only dealing with *one* statement.

Comment: Yes but i would like to implement it also with try catch if you dont mind. Could you be so kind and provide as answer?

Comment: And there will be more queries within later

Comment: The real power of transactions is when you are executing a series of Sql statements. For example, you can run multiple `UPDATE` statements, and be sure that either all of them will execute, or none of them.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the transaction from SqlConnection - apply it to your select, update, insert, delete commands in the SqlDataAdapter and then call Commit/Rollback as required.

```
Public Function GetAllByKatId(Id As Integer) As Object
    Dim result As Object
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Clear()
    Using cnn As New SqlConnection(strcon)
        cnn.Open()
        dim trans as SqlTransaction
        trans = cnn.BeginTransaction()
        Using dad As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbGet WHERE ID=@id", cnn)
            dad.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@id", Id))
            dad.SelectCommand.Transaction = trans
            dad.Fill(dt)

            If dt IsNot Nothing AndAlso dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                trans.Commit()
                result = dt
            Else
                trans.Rollback()
                result = Nothing
            End If
        End Using
        cnn.Close()
    End Using
    Return result
End Function
```